# Issue with Javafx actually opening Gui example

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, user-interface, javafx

I am having problems with javafx (surprise lol). For some reason my code seems to be running, but the actual gui never shows up on my screen, and it is stuck in the bottom right. When I take out the "implements initializable" in the Sample Controller class, then the gui shows up. I would greatly appreciate any help anyone could give me !!
Thanks

Main Class

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {


        @Override

        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            try {
                Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
                Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
                scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();


            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

Sample Controller Class

```
package application;

import java.awt.Label;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SampleController{

    @FXML 
    private ListView<String>mainListView;






    /**
     * Initializing the class
     */
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        ObservableList<String>thisMainListView = FXCollections.observableArrayList("SPY","QQQ","Rus2000");

        mainListView.setItems(thisMainListView);

    }








}
```

Comment: Please don't post [screenshots of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Instead, include the code directly in the question, properly [formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Ok, is this fine for this time? Never posted on here before

Comment: Can you just [edit] the question? You might also post the version that does run correctly, and the FXML file. It seems weird that one would work and one wouldn't. The more chance you give others to be able to reproduce the issue, the more chance there is you'll get an answer.

Comment: Please paste the code into the question as text. Also, this has nothing to do with python, so please remove that tag.

Comment: You seem to have a lot of imports that you are not using. Also if you were using `Label`, `import java.awt.Label;` would not be the correct import.

Comment: Do you get an exception? The only possible issue caused by the `initialize` method I can think of would be a NPE caused by `mainListView` not proberly being injected (or parts of the code you aren't showing).

Comment: @Sedrick That might be the solution, I got the gui to start pulling up when I run the main class, but the ListView is still not populating which could potentially be due to that reason